# United Kingdom Language Pack

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation, language-package

Does anyone know where the United Kingdom Language Pack has gone.

I cannot find it at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-experience/internationalization-localization.html

Welsh is there - but not UK English?

I am after installing via Connect to a 1.9.1 version so we have basket and VAT etc etc

Comment: I see many references to http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/GavinPearce/extension/365/magento-community-modules--english-united-kingdom-language-pack about on the web - but it seems that this file is no longer there - does anyone know where it went?

Comment: does the default American pack not work for you? I don't want to pick your pride but there is so little difference that it might just be quicker to manually change what you see and not invest many hours in looking for the en_GB pack. Just my 2ct...

Comment: Thank for the reply Yorrd. You would think so, but actually there are many changes to make. Change Tax to VAT, change Cart to Basket, change Zip to Postcode, change Shipping to Delivery and many more. And of these, they are mentioned multiple times in different files - it takes hours to do, much easier to install the language pack. Just very odd that it is not there anymore?!?!

Comment: ok, I get your point... Just checking my installation, there is a en_GB directory in `/locale`, but there's nothing in it :D no idea what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

Answered this here [English (GB) Language pack for Magento 1.9.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57820/english-gb-language-pack-for-magento-1-9-1/64152#64152)

Installing via connect I have not tried - Would usually upload via GIT or FTP into the app/locale directory

> ALL credit to Lightnest - www.lightnest.co.uk
>
> http://www.lightnest.co.uk/magento-en_gb-united-kingdom-language-pack/
>   I also uploaded to GitHub
>   https://github.com/ecommerceheroes/magento_GB_LP .
>
> Had the same issue whilst trying to locate the GB language pack. I am
>   aware that just posting links as an answer is NOT the stack overflow
>   way but this is where the language pack can be found --
>
> ALL credit to Lightnest - www.lightnest.co.uk
>
> http://www.lightnest.co.uk/magento-en_gb-united-kingdom-language-pack/
>   I also uploaded to GitHub
>   https://github.com/ecommerceheroes/magento_GB_LP

.