# Change Magento Cart to UK fields

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address

Hoping this is really simple but nothing seems that simple in Magento...But at the moment my cart says Country, State/Province, Zip.

BUT it's a UK shop, so how do I change these to the relevant county/postcode inputs?

I've changed everything I can possibly find to UK and I cant seem to make this show county and Postcode?

Big thanks in advance for any help on how I can change this.

Answer (score 0):

To change cart to Basket and ZIP code to Post code you need to install the local GB language which is removed from Magento connect -- only God knows why.

You can get it from here [English (GB) Language pack for Magento 1.9.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57820/english-gb-language-pack-for-magento-1-9-1)

For the Count input you need to make sure the your local is United Kingdom please see image attached[image]